# Shared Files in TFS 2010

Tags: php, tfs

I'm fairly new to TFS 2010, so please excuse any naivety. My organization uses it to manage all the code for their Windows products. I've been tasked with migrating our web applications to the same system.

There are multiple projects, all in PHP, and (through what seems to be to me crazy InvokeProcess voodoo) I have the builds successfully pushing to our UNIX staging and live servers.

The problem is shared headers and footers on the web pages. From my research I've found that TFS does not support sharing or linking of source code. However I'm curious if anyone else has been in this or a similar situation and how they managed to solve it.

Basically I'm looking for a way to have consistent headers and footers among all the PHP applications while only needing to change one file when I need to update them.

Any advice will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not familiar with PHP, so I don't know if it is possible to use re-use a file. In visual studio for example you can pull in a file from any location. In that case the sharing is done because each application is using the same file.

If that is not possible, you can use branching to create linked copies of the file. If there is a new version of the file, you need to merge those changes to all the branches.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I was able to set up branches in each of my projects an accomplish what I was after with a baseless merge.